# Fetch values in interdependent array of struct in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, circular-dependency

I have many interdependent array of structures. Im struggling hard with member variable pointers to a record in array of another struct. 
Putting 3 structs for your reference

```
struct struct1 {
int node_id;
struct2* ptr; };

struct struct2 {
int node_id;
int type;
struct1* owner;
struct2* next;
struct2* previous;
struct3* block1;
struct3* block2; };

struct struct3 {
int node_id;
int n_entries;
struct3* next_block; };
```

now my question is how can I fetch records for struct1. I knew that it can be as

```
struct1 pstruct1;
```

`struct2 pstruct2;`

```
pstruct.ptr = &pstruct2;
```

probably if I have one set of records in each struct.
But what should i use for array of struct, if it is something similar to this,

```
pstruct1[i].ptr = &pstruct2[j];
```

How do I find 'j' value? Also is it possible to write a common function with argument struct of undefined member variable, so that it accepts the structure passed from calling function? Sorry if any of my coding is wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I can not follow what is your problem

Comment: If I understand you right, you ave an array of `struct2`, and wonder how to find a single entry in that array?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yeah you are absolutely right

Comment: Use a `for` loop from `0` to the number of entries in the array, and compare some member variable in a condition only you can know, and when found you have `j`, which is the loop variable.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yeah... but it works only if i pass the same struct as argument. I wanna repeat this function to all structs of different member variable. I'm trying with Template functions as John mentioned in the answer below. Thanks anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is right

```
pstruct.ptr = &pstruct2;
```

This is right

```
pstruct1[i].ptr = &pstruct2[j];
```

Your first question 'How do I find the j value?'

I have no idea, it's your program only you can know what it's supposed to do and how j is supposed to be calculated.

Your second question 'Also is it possible to write a common function with argument struct of undefined member variable, so that it accepts the structure passed from calling function?'

I think you are talking about a template functions.

```
template <class T>
void common_function(const T& struc)
{
}
```

You can call that function with any struct. But templates are a difficult topic, you should get a book on C++ that exaplains them.

Comment: Thank you John for your response. will give a go with template functions as i have no other choice. And as you had said 'j' is to be calculated, i think i can make use of the template function to return j value (from array of struct) if I'm not going wrong :-p

Comment: @Flouri Virtual functions (aka polymorphism) is probably another thing you could try.